# What is the correct regular expression for getting all <h3> of <h2> in a Group?

Tags: php, regex

TEST STRING: view-source:http://www.shiksha.com/b-tech/colleges/b-tech-colleges-chennai

Regular Expression:

```html
(<ul class="facility-icons">
(<li class="emptyDesc">
<i class="fc_icons ic_fac_(.+)">
<div class="srpHoverCntnt2">
<h3>(.+)<\/h3>
<p><\/p>
<\/div>
<\/i>
<\/li>)+)
<\/ul>
```

error: Regular Expression is not matching the subject string

I want the facilities of a college in a group. How can I correct this regular expression or what another way can I extract that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: The question is very different as I need an array of arrays where arrays are the facilities of a college and array is the list of colleges.

Comment: The answer is the same. 'Just use a parser, not a regex'.